# python 'unflow' format=flowed email

Tags: python, email, thunderbird

When sending

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

in an email on one line as quoted above, thunderbird converts it to this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua.
```

I believe, this somehow has to do with this `format=flowed` header:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

When displaying the mail in thunderbird, it looks perfectly okay. The line is displayed as one line.
However, when parsing it using pythons `Message.get_payload` the newlines are still displayed, completely destroying the readability.

How can I make python convert these 'flowed' lines of text to normal ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`formatflowed` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/formatflowed) to convert such text to 'regular' text:

```
from formatflowed import convertToWrapped

text = convertToWrapped(msg.get_payload(), character_set=msg.get_charset())
```

Do note that you need to pass in a *byte string*, not a `unicode` value; the library decodes to Unicode for you.

Obligatory disclaimer: I am the author of that library, albeit quite some time ago now.

Comment: Even though it would be neater to have this in python-core it looks very cool, thanks! I am going to try it out now.

Comment: Does this support unicode? It directly generated this error for me: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)` Unicode char 'xf6' is the german umlaut `ö`. Nothing special. Do I need to set something else? I posted the trace here: http://pastebin.com/TKJUggxx

Comment: Add a `character_set` parameter specifying the codec, but do pass in a byte string (IIRC).

Comment: Hmm, I am still having slight problems with this. Can you join me in chat so I don't need to post so much code in the comments? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34864/python-unflow-formatflowed-email

Comment: Thunderbird also adds breaks in the `subject` header. When using it on the subject header it didn't remove the newlines though. How can I get this working? Snippet here: http://pastebin.com/tHx8c8pP

Comment: Message headers are never in `format-flowed` format; they are always plain text or use quoted-printable encoding to make them plain text.

Comment: It is a standard plain-text header. RFC-compliant headers stay within a line length limit by breaking on whitespace across multiple lines with whitespace prepended. Split the header on `[ ]+\n` and rejoin with one space. `' '.join([line.lstrip(' ') for line in header.split('\n')])` would do it too.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that this is enforced by RFC. Never seen it before. Thanks for the enlightenment ;-)

Comment: This solution works like a charm but with a caveat. convertToWrapped has a parameter ("width") with default value 78, which in practice means that new line brakes are added at character 78. The result is that the output of convertToWrapped still has some line breaks where they shouldn't be. A solution to this is to specify a very high value for "width": `text = convertToWrapped(msg.get_payload(), character_set=msg.get_charset(), width=10000000000000000000)`